# Can we create stored procedure in ms access 2007

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures

How can we create stored procedure in MS Access 2007. If we can then how should write procedure for insert statement.

Comment: The way to do this is to read the documentation and do what it says.

Comment: It is possible to create an `INSERT` query by executing a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create stored procedures in MS Access 2007. You need Access 2013 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845861(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I  beg your pardon. It is now clear that the OP wants to use CREATE PROCEDURE directly in Access (but has tagged its question with C# hence the misunderstanding)  If you want to edit your question I can remove my downvote

Comment: No worries. To be honest I noticed the C# tag only after your downvote :-)

Comment: I didn't quite get that part about editing the question btw.

Comment: After a certain amount of time, a downvote cannot be removed. Only if the OP (you) changes/edit its answer the downvoter (me) can remove the -1

Comment: Done. Btw it seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673971/can-make-stored-procedure-or-function-in-access-2003. I think it'll be better off being tagged as such (I don't have rights yet)

Answer (score 1):

This statement could be used as an example

```
string queryText = @"
CREATE PROCEDURE Customer_Insert (pName  text(255), pAddress Text(255)) AS
    INSERT INTO Customers ( Name, Address )
    VALUES ([pName], [pAddress]);";
```

Now the usual way to execute a non returning rows command with OleDb

```
using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(......))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryText, cn))
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And finally you could call it in the usual way

```
using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(......))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Customer_Insert", cn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = "yourCustomerName";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pAddress", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = "yourCustomerAddress";
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**EDIT**
Creating a stored procedure (A.K.A. Query in Access interface) should be done only if the StoredProcedure doesn't exist. To discover if the procedure already exists in your db the simplest way to do it is the following

```
 using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(....));    
 { 
     con.Open();
     var schema = con.GetSchema("Procedures");
     DataRow[] r = schema.Select("PROCEDURE_NAME = 'Customer_Insert'");
     if(r.Length > 0)
         MessageBox.Show("Procedure 'Customer_Insert' already exists");
 }
```

Comment: where to write these code

Comment: This is an example of course. The creation of the Procedure should be in some sort of code that updates your database (You could call the GetSchema from an open connection to know if you have already the procedure in place) The code that uses the procedure should be whereever you need it

Comment: I havn't find the way to write stored procedure in ms access 2007. Is there any way to write? when I am writing code query wizard giving error

Comment: This code should be executed using a Visual Studio project in C#, are you executing this directly in Access? If yes why did you tag your question with C#?

Comment: I have removed the tag now

Comment: Well, fine then. Of course, as pointed in another answer. with MS-Access you cannot execute a query that starts with CREATE PROCEDURE.  I will leave my answer because it could be of interest to other users that search for the terms of your title

Comment: can you please answer instead of finding duplicates and downvote

Comment: Apart from the fact that I haven't downvoted you, I wish to ask if the duplicate is your answer or not? If not why?